# how to set the timer in c#

Tags: c#, directx, timer

i am drawing numerous lines in screen . i need to put timer and draw the lines in panel one by one in c# using directx

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: Post information about what are you doing now, what do want to achieve (its not anywhere informative what you've written) and then we can talk about giving an answer. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm stabbing in the dark here because of the lack of information given, but if you're just asking for a way to time something, C# has the `StopWatch` class found in `System.Diagnostics`, it measures time in tenths of milliseconds

Usage Example:

```
using System.Diagnostics

public static void TestStopWatch()
{
 StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();

 int temp = 0;
 int repetitions = 1000000;

 sw.Reset();
 for (int i=0; i<repetitions; i++)
  temp++;
long time = sw.Peek();   
Console.WriteLine("Time = " + time/10.0 + " milliseconds.");
}
```

Example Output:

```
2.7 milliseconds
```